# I want to remove certain parts of a certain string in Powershell 7.2.4, how do I do it?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0, powershell-7.2

I have the string `"url": "https://maven.fabricmc.net/net/fabricmc/fabric-installer/0.11.0/fabric-installer-0.11.0.jar"`. I want to remove everything from the string except `https://maven.fabricmc.net/net/fabricmc/fabric-installer/0.11.0/fabric-installer-0.11.0.jar` (I want to remove the quotes as well).

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = """url"": ""https://maven.fabricmc.net/net/fabricmc/fabric-installer/0.11.0/fabric-installer-0.11.0.jar"""
$str.Split(""": """)[1].Replace("""","")
```

Comment: Add a bit of text to explain what you're doing and maybe the doc for the function you use (nice to have)

Answer (score 0):

The shortest I could think of
Might have the incorrect indexnumber, just test switching '3'

```
( $str -split """ )[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `-replace` operator and extract the section you want.

```
'"url": "https://maven.fabricmc.net/net/fabricmc/fabric-installer/0.11.0/fabric-installer-0.11.0.jar"' -replace '"url": "(.+)"','$1'
```

However since this appears to be in JSON format you may be better off using `ConvertFrom-Json` on the entire thing and then accessing the property through dot notation.

It's slightly easier than trying to regex or string match sections of JSON.

```
$converted = Get-Content file.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$converted.url
```

Comment: It does not have the object brackets that are seen in JSON.
I have the string only without the brackets.

Comment: You could prepend,append to make it valid JSON too. `'{0}{1}{2}' -f '{', $string, '}' | ConvertFrom-Json`